# Como mostrar un Excel con PhpSpreadsheet al cargar la informacion

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Actualmente estoy usando la libreria de PHPSpreadsheet para llevar valores de PHP  a Excel, lo qe hace ahora es de llevar los valores a un excel y almacenarlos en la direccion que yo especifico. pero lo que busco es que cuando yo cargue informacion, me muestre el excel para abrir. Cuando usaba el PHPExcel si se podia, y se hacia con: $objWriter->save('php://output') entonces se mostraba el excel para abrir. Mi codigo con PHPSpreadsheet es el sgte:

```
<?php 
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
 $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
 $a="we";
 $a1="are";
 $a2="the";
 $a3="world"; 

  $sheet->setCellValue('A2', $a);
  $sheet->setCellValue('c2', $a1);
  $sheet->setCellValue('E2', $a2);
  $sheet->setCellValue('G2', $a3);

  $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
  $writer->save('C:\xampp\ejemplo.xlsx');

 ?>
```

se podra realizar?

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir el documento y que el navegador lo pueda abrir una opción es hacerlo así:

- Establecer los encabezados correspondientes al formato del archivo de salida (*en este caso .xlsx*)
- Indicar en método `save` que imprima la salida en `php://output` (*no en un archivo*)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php 
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$a="we";
$a1="are";
$a2="the";
$a3="world"; 

$sheet->setCellValue('A2', $a);
$sheet->setCellValue('c2', $a1);
$sheet->setCellValue('E2', $a2);
$sheet->setCellValue('G2', $a3);

// Aquí
$filename = 'test.xlsx';

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede hacer de la manera que lo esta planteando con algunos cambios; de esta manera crea y descarga el archivo. Dependiendo como tenga configurado las descargas en su navegador, lo va a descargar directamente o le pide la ruta en que quiera guardarlo.

```
    require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    $a="we";

    $a1="are";

    $a2="the";

    $a3="world"; 


    $sheet->setCellValue('A2', $a);

    $sheet->setCellValue('C2', $a1);

    $sheet->setCellValue('E2', $a2);

    $sheet->setCellValue('G2', $a3);

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);


   try {

      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
      $writer->save("php://output");
  }
    catch(Exception $e){

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Comment: buenas, lo que quiero es que cuando ingrese desde mi pagina, osea localhost/mifolder/index.php y de enter, me muestre donde yo quiero almacenarlo... osea la ventana de archivo para yo escoger donde lo guardare(si en mi escritorio, en mi C: o en mis documentos, etc)

Comment: la solucion que ustedes brindan esta bueno, pero me muestra lo mismo que mi codigo que puse para hacer la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

yo lo que he realizado es un petición ajax para generar el archivo y al final envio la respuesta con la url donde ha generado el archivo <--- php.
Seguidamente en el JS con la petición ajax, en el done o success, agregas un href.location con la url que enviaste desde php, haciendo esto, te pide donde guardar el archivo.

PHP

```
$nameFile = "excelNew.xlsx";
$saveFile = "/xls/". $nameFile;
$downFile = "http://turutadedominio.com/xls/" . $nameFile;

$writer->save($saveFile);
echo json_encode($downFile);

$sheet->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($sheet);
```

Luego en el JS (uso jquery, si solo usas javascript utiliza el window.open)

```
...
.done(function(resp) {
    location.href = resp.xlsx;
})
```

Luego puedes usar unlink para borrar el archivo del servidor.
Un saludo.